# Bing maps changing image pixel values

Tags: bitmap, hex, bing-maps

I would like to know if an issue I am having in downloading and stitching some Bing maps. I will try and give as much information as I can because the problem is somewhat strange.

**The Task**

To programmatically stitch multiple screenshots from bing maps by saving them as uncompressed 24bit bitmaps and aligning them by the hex values.

**The proof it can be done**

This process is already successful with google maps. This is not a coding issue, but much stranger.

**The Theory**

Take the following two images

[Left Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11uwF.png) and [Right Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVDat.png) (can be saved off as uncompressed 24bit bmps)

The right most column of the left image will also exist in the right image. Where this column exists is the overlap required to successfully stitch the images together.

However when I look at the hex this is not the case. The right hand column of the left image, and any of the columns before that do not exist anywhere and are **very different** The last three pixels of the left image on the bottom row are `28 46 59 2B 49 5C 2F 4B 5C` and this does not exist anywhere in the other image.

**So things I have thought of so far**

Some misalignment of the images

- The images perfectly align in Photoshop with no misalignment
- I also searched for pixel groups from the centre rows

Some small border present

- Verified there is no border in Photoshop

Some alteration to the brightness/contrast by Bing

- This appears to be the case but I can't find anywhere to confirm this.

I appreciate any help I can get as to why this would be occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stich images from Bing Maps there are a couple of options:

- Use the REST Imagery service, it already provides stitched images that are easy to access. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff701724.aspx
- Stitch the map tiles. These are already designed to be easily align programmatically using the well documented tile structure here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx Doing this is fairly easy and is how all other developers do custom stitching of Bing Maps imagery.

Now, if you do any stitching of Bing Maps imagery there are some important things you must do:

- Make sure your final images align with the Print rights of Bing Maps: https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/print-rights.html
- Make sure the Bing logo and copyrights are on the image.
- Make sure that each time you generate an image an authenticated request is made to Bing Maps. For example, if you stich map tiles, call the REST imagery metadata service first to get the latest tile URL's, this will also authenticate the request. If using the REST imagery service to generate an image, you already have to pass in a key, so all good. More info on the process for directly access Bing Maps tiles can be found here: https://1drv.ms/w/s!AgFqp4QkIjUNlrh2b-9OQDG0JcVo2Q

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I have other functionality that I wanted to include. I have incorporated GMap.Net into a solution. Thanks again